# How to hot reboot android device

Tags: android, command, reboot

Does anyone know the command to hot reboot that you would use in the terminal emeulator? Would it be a command similar to the the normal reboot commands.  If anyone could help thankx.

Answer (score 3):

Probably depends on what do you mean by *hot*.
Anyway, you can use:

```
   $ adb -s <SERIALNO> reboot
```

or

```
   $ adb -s <SERIALNO> shell 'stop; sleep 5; start'
```